# Selecting a balanced subset of combinations

Tags: python, combinations, subset

I have an array containing N elements. I want to select M K-combinations of them such that the elements are as evenly distributed as possible (that is, all N elements are there the same number of times, and are paired (or tripled, or etc) with each other as evenly as possible.

For example, this is trivial - or at least easy enough, if time consuming - to do by hand with the values of:

```
N = 8  
M = 14  
K = 4
```

With 14*4 possible spots, each of the 8 elements will appear 14 * 4 / 8 = 7 times. In addition, each element will have 7 * (4-1) = 21 'partners', which means each of the other 7 elements will appear with it 21 / 7 = 3 times. Similarly, since each pair appears three times, there are 3 * (4-2) = 6 spots left in those sets, which are filled perfectly with the other 6 elements. Thus, each element appears 7 times, each pair thrice, and each triplet is unique, and all triplets are present. With a few arbitrary decisions about where to start building this set, this took me maybe ten minutes to fill in.

What I would like to know is if there is a method of doing this (preferably in Python) for the general case, or at the very least, a case with slightly less perfect combinations, such as the one I'm working on now:

```
N = 12
M = 22
K = 6
```

Some of the same logic from before still works. Each element appears 22 * 6 / 12 = 11 times, and each one has 11 * (6-1) = 55 partners, so each of the other 11 elements pair with it 5 times. In these five pairings, there are 5 * (6-2) = 20 spots remaining, which the other 10 elements fill twice each. So each element appears 11 times, each pair five times, and each triplet twice. Unfortunately, moving up to the next step doesn't work, as the triplets have 2 * (6-3) = 6 empty spaces to be filled with the 9 remaining elements, so while the quadruplets should be unique, they are not all present.

I've tried to approach this mathematically, as you can see, but I'm hoping there's a way I can make Python do the heavy lifting (and randomization) for me. Any ideas?

Comment: I'm thinking a combination of `itertools.combination(N_list, K_elements)` and `random.choice(combs)` `M` times, but that will be expensive to generate all possible combinations just to choose a few. But maybe that can get you started.

Comment: See balanced subset optimization problem https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/13088/subset-optimization-problem